# criar sequência que aumente e diminua monotonicamente

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte vetor:

```
> a
 [1]  64.42  66.99 100.39  97.96  97.96  96.26  94.22  92.35  86.05  84.01
```

Desejo que possa gerar outro vetor que cresça e diminua de forma monotônica, seja qual for o incremento que eu escolha. A saída para este vetor com o incremento de 1 seria:

```
> b
 [1]  1  2  3  2  1 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
```

O ideal seria não utilizar um loop.

Comment: Os 4º e 5º valores são iguais, portanto não deveria ser a saída `1  2  3  2  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3`? (Dois valores iguais a `2`, nas mesmas posições.)

Comment: exato, vou editar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro os dados.

```
a <- scan(text = "64.42  66.99 100.39  97.96  97.96
                  96.26  94.22  92.35  86.05  84.01")
```

Agora, se o meu comentário acima está correto, podemos resolver o problema com uma única linha de código `R`.

```
d <- cumsum(c(1, sign(diff(a))))
d
[1]  1  2  3  2  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
```

Por exemplo, com uma sequência que não tenha dois valores consecutivos iguais, o mesmo comando dá o resultado pretendido.

```
set.seed(4863)
b <- runif(10, 60, 110)
b <- c(sort(b[1:3]), sort(b[4:10], decreasing = TRUE))
b

cumsum(c(1, sign(diff(b))))
[1]  1  2  3  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2
```

Isto pode ser escrito como uma função de uma linha.

```
sobe_desce <- function(x) cumsum(c(1, sign(diff(x))))
```

Comment: Obrigado Rui, bem simples o código.